# IF statement in MySQL results in Error Code 1064 

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to nest an if statement in what will eventually become a routine.

```
SET @foo = (SELECT foo FROM table WHERE id = 1);
SET @bar = (SELECT bar FROM table WHERE id = 1);

IF @foo = @bar THEN SET @thisVar = 1;
ELSE SET @thisVar = 0;
END IF

SELECT @thisVar;
```

But I get:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IF @foo = @bar THEN SET @thisVar = 1;'at line 1)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what's up there, but why does the error say line 1?  Perhaps the issue is that you're not actually running the whole procedure.

You can try using the IF() function like this:

```
SET @thisVar = IF(@foo = @bar, 1, 0);
```

I think this is shorter and cleaner for simple if/else assignments.

Comment: I believe it's because the SET commands above are run and counted as an individual procedure themselves.  I'll try the command you've suggested.  I'm writing it in Workbench which is underlining it red, but won't tell me what's wrong.

Comment: @jdborg try removing the semicolons from the 2 SET statements up top, and adding one at the end of ENDIF.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping into a procedure appears fine when everything is declared.  Also removed the @'s.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DO_SOMETHING`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _foo VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE _bar VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE _thisVar INT;

    SET _foo = 'test';
    SET _bar = 'test';

    IF _foo = _bar THEN SET _thisVar = 1;
    ELSE SET _thisVar = 0;
    END IF;

    SELECT _thisVar;
END
```

Comment: I thought it might be this problem.  Will check again once I've finished the procedure.